# How to Have keyboard avoiding view correctly in React native

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**

I have created a form in react native with keyboard avoiding view but when all the error messages of input fields have been shown the view is not avoiding the keyboard. This is my code.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  BackHandler,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import AppText from "_components/appText";
import { strings } from "_translations/i18n";
import styles from "./newpatientstyles";
import SubmitButton from "_components/submitButton";

const NewPatient = () => {
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }} enabled>
      <View style={styles.patientView}>
        <View style={styles.patientTitleView}>
          <AppText styles={styles.patientTitle}>
            {strings("new-patient.title")}
          </AppText>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.patient}>
          <View style={styles.patientContainer}>
            <AppText styles={styles.patientFormTitle}>
              {strings("new-patient.form-title")}
            </AppText>
            <View style={styles.formContainer}>
              <Formik
                initialValues={{
                  firstname: "",
                  lastname: "",
                  address: "",
                  age: "",
                  gender: "",
                  mobileNo: "",
                }}
                validationSchema={Yup.object({
                  firstname: Yup.string().required("First Name required"),
                  lastname: Yup.string().required("Last Name required"),
                  address: Yup.string().required("Address required"),
                  age: Yup.string().required("Age required"),
                  gender: Yup.string().required("Gender required"),
                  mobileNo: Yup.string().required("Mobile No required"),
                })}
                onSubmit={(values, formikActions) => {
                  // _onPress(values);
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    formikActions.setSubmitting(false);
                  }, 500);
                }}
              >
                {(formprops) => (
                  <View>
                    <View style={styles.inputView}>
                      <TextInput
                        style={styles.textField}
                        placeholder="Firstname"
                        placeholderTextColor="#bbbbbb"
                        value={formprops.values.firstname}
                        onChangeText={formprops.handleChange("firstname")}
                        onBlur={formprops.handleBlur("firstname")}
                        keyboardType="default"
                      />
                    </View>
                    {formprops.touched.firstname &&
                    formprops.errors.firstname ? (
                      <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                        <AppText styles={styles.errorMessageText}>
                          {formprops.errors.firstname}
                        </AppText>
                      </View>
                    ) : null}
                    <View style={styles.inputView}>
                      <TextInput
                        style={styles.textField}
                        placeholder="Lastname"
                        placeholderTextColor="#bbbbbb"
                        value={formprops.values.lastname}
                        onChangeText={formprops.handleChange("lastname")}
                        onBlur={formprops.handleBlur("lastname")}
                        keyboardType="default"
                      />
                    </View>
                    {formprops.touched.lastname && formprops.errors.lastname ? (
                      <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                        <AppText styles={styles.errorMessageText}>
                          {formprops.errors.lastname}
                        </AppText>
                      </View>
                    ) : null}
                    <View style={styles.inputView}>
                      <TextInput
                        style={styles.textField}
                        placeholder="Address"
                        placeholderTextColor="#bbbbbb"
                        value={formprops.values.address}
                        onChangeText={formprops.handleChange("address")}
                        onBlur={formprops.handleBlur("address")}
                        keyboardType="default"
                      />
                    </View>
                    {formprops.touched.address && formprops.errors.address ? (
                      <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                        <AppText styles={styles.errorMessageText}>
                          {formprops.errors.address}
                        </AppText>
                      </View>
                    ) : null}
                    <View
                      style={
                        (!formprops.touched.age ? styles.inputView : null) ||
                        (formprops.touched.age && formprops.values.age
                          ? styles.validInputView
                          : null) ||
                        (formprops.touched.age && formprops.errors.age
                          ? styles.inputViewError
                          : null)
                      }
                    >
                      <TextInput
                        style={styles.textField}
                        placeholder="Age"
                        placeholderTextColor="#bbbbbb"
                        value={formprops.values.age}
                        onChangeText={formprops.handleChange("age")}
                        onBlur={formprops.handleBlur("age")}
                        keyboardType="default"
                      />
                    </View>
                    {formprops.touched.age && formprops.errors.age ? (
                      <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                        <AppText styles={styles.errorMessageText}>
                          {formprops.errors.age}
                        </AppText>
                      </View>
                    ) : null}
                    <View
                      style={
                        (!formprops.touched.mobileNo
                          ? styles.inputView
                          : null) ||
                        (formprops.touched.mobileNo && formprops.values.mobileNo
                          ? styles.validInputView
                          : null) ||
                        (formprops.touched.mobileNo && formprops.errors.mobileNo
                          ? styles.inputViewError
                          : null)
                      }
                    >
                      <TextInput
                        style={styles.textField}
                        placeholder="Mobile No"
                        placeholderTextColor="#bbbbbb"
                        value={formprops.values.mobileNo}
                        onChangeText={formprops.handleChange("mobileNo")}
                        onBlur={formprops.handleBlur("mobileNo")}
                        keyboardType="default"
                      />
                      {formprops.touched.mobileNo &&
                      formprops.errors.mobileNo ? (
                        <Icon name="times" size={25} style={styles.errorIcon} />
                      ) : null}
                      {formprops.touched.mobileNo &&
                      formprops.values.mobileNo ? (
                        <Icon name="check" size={25} style={styles.validIcon} />
                      ) : null}
                    </View>
                    {formprops.touched.mobileNo && formprops.errors.mobileNo ? (
                      <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                        <AppText styles={styles.errorMessageText}>
                          {formprops.errors.mobileNo}
                        </AppText>
                      </View>
                    ) : null}
                    <SubmitButton
                      onpress={formprops.handleSubmit}
                      btext={strings("login.button-text")}
                    />
                  </View>
                )}
              </Formik>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.hr} />
        <View style={styles.patientBottomContainer}>
          <View style={styles.patientBottomView}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <AppText styles={styles.bottomLinkText}>
                {strings("new-patient.bottom-link")}
              </AppText>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

export default NewPatient;
```

This is how I organized my stylings.

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  colempty: {
    height: 150,
  },
  patient: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  patientView: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  patientTitleView: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: '5%',
  },
  patientTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '300',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#444444',
  },
  patientFormTitle: {
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: '200',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#444444',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  hr: {
    marginTop: -30,
    borderBottomColor: '#c3c3c3',
    borderBottomWidth: 2.0,
    marginRight: 30,
    marginLeft: 30,
  },
  patientBottomContainer: {
    height: 50,
  },
  patientBottomView: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  patientBottomContainerText: {
    fontSize: 13,
    color: '#444444',
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  formContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginRight: 30,
    marginLeft: 30,
  },
  patientBottomLinkView: {
    paddingLeft: 20,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  patientBottomContainerTextView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    paddingLeft: 30,
  },
  bottomLinkText: {
    fontSize: 13,
    color: '#484848',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: '#c3c3c3',
  },
  errorMessage: {},
  errorMessageText: {
    color: '#ff3d3d',
    fontSize: 18,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  patientContainer: {
    marginTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
    height: 600,
    elevation: 10,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 3},
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowRadius: 5,
  },
  submitButtonView: {
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  patienterrorInput: {
    marginTop: 40,
    borderBottomColor: '#ff3d3d',
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  inputView: {
    marginTop: 5,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderBottomColor: '#cccccc',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
  },
  inputViewError: {
    // flex: 1,
    marginTop: 5,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderBottomColor: '#ff3d3d',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
  },
  validInputView: {
    marginTop: 5,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderBottomColor: '#007aff',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
  },
  errorIcon: {
    marginTop: 15,
    color: '#ff3d3d',
  },
  validIcon: {
    marginTop: 15,
    color: '#007aff',
  },
  textField: {
    flex: 1,
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '500',
    paddingLeft: 0,
  },
});

export default styles;
```

This is the view when loading looks.
[image]

This is how the view looks when all the error messages are shown.

[image]

Can someone help me to correctly used this keyboard avoiding view? I tried a lot to make it work but I was unable to do so. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For these situations we can use one of **these methods:**

1.wrapping Component with `<ScrollView></ScrollView>`

2.wrapping Component with `<KeyboardAvoidingView></KeyboardAvoidingView>` if you are already using this method check out https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview#keyboardverticaloffset

Sometimes our wrong given styles can make these happens too such as : **Having a fixed value for our styles**, check your margins and use one of the given methods

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, ScrollView, Platform } from "react-native";

// KeyboardAvoidWrapper Component
const HKeyBoardAvoidWrapper = ({ children, contentContainerStyle, scrollEnabled }) => {
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 10 : null}
      style={{flex : 1 }}
      behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : null}
    >
      <ScrollView
        nestedScrollEnabled={true}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        bounces={false}
        scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
        contentContainerStyle={contentContainerStyle}
      >
        {children}
      </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

export default HKeyBoardAvoidWrapper;
```

To use the HKeyBoardAvoidWrapper component correctly, follow these steps:

1. Import the HKeyBoardAvoidWrapper component into your desired screen or component.
2. Wrap your form or content that you want to be keyboard-avoidant with the HKeyBoardAvoidWrapper component. You can pass your form elements or other content as children to this wrapper. For example:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import HKeyBoardAvoidWrapper from "./HKeyBoardAvoidWrapper";

const MyFormScreen = () => {
  return (
    <HKeyBoardAvoidWrapper contentContainerStyle={styles.container} scrollEnabled={false}>
      <View style={styles.formContainer}>
        <TextInput placeholder="Username" style={styles.input} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Password" style={styles.input} secureTextEntry />
        {/* Add more form elements here */}
      </View>
    </HKeyBoardAvoidWrapper>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  formContainer: {
    width: "80%",
    // Add more styling for your form container
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
});

export default MyFormScreen;
```

1. You can customize the behavior of the HKeyBoardAvoidWrapper component by using the following props:

- contentContainerStyle: Allows you to apply styles to the content
  container inside the ScrollView. Use this prop to control how your
  form or content is displayed when the keyboard appears.
- scrollEnabled: Set this prop to true if you want the content inside
  the ScrollView to be scrollable. If set to false, the content won't
  be scrollable even if it exceeds the screen height.

2. Additionally, the keyboardVerticalOffset and behavior props of the
   KeyboardAvoidingView are used to configure the vertical offset and
   behavior of the view when the keyboard is shown on iOS.